# "Localizar e substituir" com expressões regulares no MS Word 2016

Tags: regex, microsoft-word

Eu tenho uma lista com o [resultado dos candidatos de um concurso público](http://cdn.quadrix.org.br/web/visualizar.html?file=http://cdn.quadrix.org.br/Archives/General/17053/17404/17533/9E0DB8399609/5_CFO_resultado_preliminar_prova_objetiva_medio.pdf) que eu quero classificar por nota. No entanto, antes de fazer a classificação preciso remover o número de inscrição de cada concorrente, que segue o seguinte formato, para todos:

`380.01227119/3`

Como eu posso usar uma expressão regular na função "Localizar e substituir" do MS Word 2016 para remover todos os números de inscrição?

**Edit 1 - Amostra do conteúdo do arquivo**

```
380.01229569/6; ADAILDSON DE OLIVEIRA MAIA FREITAS; 18,50; 4,50; 38,00; 61,00 / 380.01245362/3; ADAILSON GASPAR DE JESUS; 8,50;  12,50;  24,00;  45,00  /  380.01238440/2;  ADAILTON  SILVA  OLIVEIRA;  20,50;  6,50;  40,50;  67,50 /  380.01232099/7;  ADEILSON  DA SILVA  MARTINS;  4,00;  6,50;  27,00;  37,50  /  380.01240923/7;  ADONIAS  REBOUÇAS  DOS  SANTOS;  19,00;  11,00;  37,50;  67,50
```

Comment: Poderia colocar o formato das informações? não posso acessar o link do pdf.

Comment: Pronto, @rray, adicionei uma *sample*.

Comment: Selecione as informações depois click no botão `{  }` para formata-las. Pode deixar apenas umas 5 ou 6 linhas de exemplo. Tentei formatar porem ficou meio estranho.

Comment: você quer somente remover os números de inscrição? não quer armazenar em nenhum lugar? Microsoft Excel não seria mais indicado para formatar suas infos?

Comment: @Paz, eu só quero remover os números de inscrição mesmo, depois eu vou passar pro Excel.

Comment: @rray Fiz conforme você pediu, deixando apenas 5 linhas da lista do .PDF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode utilizar a seguinte expressão no Word: `([0-9]{3}.[0-9]{8}\/[0-9]{1};)`

Onde:

- `[0-9]{3}.`: seleciona 3 números antes do ponto + o ponto.
- `[0-9]{8}\/`: seleciona 8 números antes da barra + a barra.
- `[0-9]{1};`: seleciona 1 número antes do ponto e vírgula + o ponto e vírgula.

A expressão deve ficar entre parênteses para que o Word interprete a expressão.

Pelo que vi `\d` não é interpretado pelo Word, então deve ser substituída por `[0-9]`

Tem um [exemplo](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Localizar-e-substituir-texto-e-outros-dados-em-um-documento-do-Word-c6728c16-469e-43cd-afe4-7708c6c779b7) funcional na documentação.

---

Lembre-se de marcar a opção: `Usar caracteres curinga` quando for aplicar o filtro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar a seguinte regex `^\d+\.\d+/\d;` ela diz para capturar sempre no início um ou mais dígitos (`^\d+`) seguidos de um ponto (`.`) seguido de um ou mais dígitos (`\d+`) seguido de um barra `/` e de exatamente outro dígito.

No teste que executei utilizei a seguinte formatação para as informações:

```
380.01229569/6; ADAILDSON DE OLIVEIRA MAIA FREITAS; 18,50; 4,50; 38,00; 61,00 /
380.01245362/3; ADAILSON GASPAR DE JESUS; 8,50;  12,50;  24,00;  45,00  /
380.01238440/2;  ADAILTON  SILVA  OLIVEIRA;  20,50;  6,50;  40,50;  67,50 /
380.01232099/7;  ADEILSON  DA SILVA  MARTINS;  4,00;  6,50;  27,00;  37,50  /
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^A-Z]+
```

Não uso windows, muito menos word, mas essa regex significa:
No início da linha (^) passe por cima de tudo que até uma letra maiúscula [^A-Z].
Deve funcionar no word, pois com certeza funciona no LibreOffice